# Pass Javascript Array(that having class object) to c# via javascript web method call

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arrays

The javascript array that having a class object .

```
var Area = new Project_Area(window["ProjectComponents" + k], window["CoveredArea" + k], window["Unit" + k], window["Description" + k]);
  {(Array)}<--- ListArea.push(Area);
PageMethods.projectCostingSave(HID, ProjectCost, ListFloor, ListArea, onSuccess, onFail);
```

**C# Code:**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string projectCostingSave(String HID, String ProjectCost, Array[][Floor] ListFloor, Array ListArea)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(HID);

    for (int i = 0; i < ListFloor.Length; i++)
    {

    }
}
```

How can I get these object in c#?

Comment: thanks for editing   #dotctor